# Java Android - XmlPullParser - how can I start parsing from the beginning again?

Tags: java, android, xmlpullparser

I googled it and didn't find an answer - may be I didn't search it right.

My question is I'm parsing xml from the beginnning to the end of document - one way.
What if somewhere in the middle I need to set parser to go to the Start of Document again?

I know only myXmlPullParser.next(); (or any other next) to move forward, but I need at some condition to start parsing from the beginning of document again.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Sure. Create a new pull parser instance, using the same code as you used to create the first one. Or, try calling `setInput()` on your existing instance, providing it a fresh copy of the data.

Comment: Sounds like the answer is "no" for most use cases. I think a lot of users are 
going to be reading in a file or, more realistically, creating a stream for network data. The latter case in particular will require making a slow network call again to recreate the stream. Of course this is true for any Worker that uses streams!

Answer (score 0):

If it is reading from a file (or network) I am thinking that caching the data in an input stream and reading it back into the parser may be the fastest route.  I will work up an example